# Inline BNC voltage reducer?

Tags: voltage, bnc

I have absolutely zero knowledge on electrical engineering.

I am currently using a lock-in amplifier and a pulsed light source (with reference-output), but the reference output signal is too big and causes overload; voltage of the reference signal was measured at 1.7 V (impedance 50Ω), which is slightly higher than the acceptable input voltage of 1.5 V of the lock-in amp. The two machines are connected through BNC cables.

I am looking for a commercial device for reducing signal voltage inline. If available, I would want a device that reduces voltage by a factor of 2 (instead of subtracting voltage by a certain amount). Since I have zero knowledge in electrical engineering, I cannot make a device myself. Does anyone know a device that can do this?

Comment: If 1.7 V was without load then with 50R load, it would be 0.85V. Or did you measured with a T BNC , does it measure Vrms or Vpp?  Is the reference a square or sine wave

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding this well. I made a mistake. I used an oscilloscope which showed that Vpp is 34 V and is a square wave. I'm confused right now, because the light source module says it's supposed to be 3.3 V. It's an order of magnitude larger.

Comment: GeekyDude, some oscilloscope tips have an internal 10:1 voltage stepdown and some don't. When the wrong setting is used in the oscilloscope, a reading that is off by a factor of 10 is not an unlikely outcome.

Comment: @GeekyDude is the scope input configured for 1:1 (1x) setting? Sounds like it is configured for 10:1 (10x) setting where it expects an attenuated signal.

Comment: Thank you guys! You guys were right. It was set to 10x attenuation mode. I switched it to 1x and now I have Vpp = 3.4V. Vrms is, if I'm correct, 1.7 V. Now, the lock-in amp says max input voltage to be ±3.5V, 50 Ohm/1M Ohm. I don't understand why the amp overloads.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called an attenuator. A factor of 2 is a 6 dB attenuator. For example, this model:

https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=HAT-6%2B

You can buy something similar from other vendors as well.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean decibels in amplitude? So with a 10 dB attenuator, I should expect appox. one third of the original voltage?

Comment: @GeekyDude That is correct. Power is V^2*R, thus voltage is an amplitude term (20 log) and electrical power is a power term (10 log).